# Why does asyncio.CancelledError need to be re-raised?

Tags: python, exception, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following `aiohttp` WebSocket handler:

```py
async def websocket_handler(request):
  ws = None
  
  if 'my-websocket-clients' not in request.app:
    request.app['my-websocket-clients'] = []
  
  print('Websocket connection starting', request.path, request.query)
  
  try:
    ws = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse(autoping=True, heartbeat=10.0, compress=True)
    await ws.prepare(request)
    request.app['my-websocket-clients'].append(ws)
    print('Websocket connection ready', len(request.app['my-websocket-clients']))
    async for msg in ws:
      await websocket_message(request, ws, msg)
  except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError as e:
    print('Websocket connection was closed uncleanly ' + str(e))
    # ~~~~~~ re-raise here? ~~~~~~
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
  finally:
    try:
      await ws.close()
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()
  
  if ws in request.app['my-websocket-clients']:
    request.app['my-websocket-clients'].remove(ws)
  
  print('Websocket connection closed', len(request.app['my-websocket-clients']))
  
  if ws is None:
    ws = aiohttp.web.Response()
  return ws
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError), "*In almost all situations the exception [asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError] must be re-raised*"

Do I need to re-raise the exception in the location marked in the code? This would require me to rewrite the code which removes the client from the client list. Would I also need to re-raise the catch-all `except` block which comes after the `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` block?

Why do I need to re-raise `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` in the first place, if I should need to do that in this case? In which situations wouldn't I need to re-raise that exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of catching `CancelledError`, you need to be very careful.

Prior to `Python 3.8`, it was easy to unintentionally suppress this error with code like this:

```py
try:
    await operation()
except Exception:
    log.error('Operataion failed. Will retry later.')
```

Since Python 3.8 `CancelledError` is subclass of `BaseException` and it is necessary to always explicitly handle this error:

```py
try:
    await operation()
except CancelledError:
    # cleanup
    raise
except Exception:
    log.error('Opertaion failed. will retry later.')
```

The main issue here is that you **cannot cancel a task that suppress** `CancelledError`.

But, in any case, the recommendation *to re-raise* is not absolute and is given for the general case. If you know what you are doing, you can handle the `CancelledError` and finish the coroutine without throwing it again. It should be minded that when a task is cancelled, its cancellation will generally look like a chain of `CancelledError`s, which will be thrown from the *innermost* `await` call and thrown up the chain of `await`s, and in this case, we break this chain, and must correctly handle this situation.

In the case of the `aiohttp` websocket handler, I think it is acceptable not to re-raise the `CancelledError` if you ensure that the resources are cleaned up correctly and the handler exits.

Comment: So, since I'm awaiting `websocket_message(request, ws, msg)`, and this method could as well be awaiting something else (like a write to/read from a database), it would make sense to re-raise it so that it can get propagated into the database "driver"?

Comment: Actually, if you say that it gets thrown from the *innermost* `await` call, then it's the other way around from what I understood. It makes sense to re-raise the exception, because there is no reason to return an empty `aiohttp.web.Response()` like I was doing, but to let `aiohttp` handle it.